# C++ Force const-ness of lvalue in initializer expression

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-value, lvalue

I would like the compiler to enforce const-ness of an lvalue (non-reference) but don't know if this is possible in C++. An example:

```
int foo() { return 5; }

int main() {
  // Is there anything I can add to the declaration of foo()
  // that would make the following cause a compile-error?
  int a = foo();

  // Whereas this compiles fine.
  const int a = foo();
}
```

Comment: What's a "non-reference lvalue"? "Lvalue" is a kind of expression, and expressions are never references.

Comment: int& a = b; // reference lvalue

Comment: There's still no "lvalue" in your code. You are defining a variable with an initalizer expression.

Comment: No. That's a definition of a variable.

Comment: Since you return a copy, out of curiosity why do you need this?

Comment: @RafaelSpring Yes, that's an lvalue reference.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ: It's an lvalue reference, but not a "reference lvalue". The latter doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, it's an lvalue reference then. Now that we've sorted out these technicalities, can we agree that they are of minor importance for the question asked?

Comment: @TommyA The returned object may contain buffers and I'd like to use const-ness of the wrapping object to enforce immutability of the contained buffers.

Comment: I've edited the title now to reflect the fact that the question is not about a regular assignment but rather an initializer expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really possible with something like an `int` because you need to give access to read the int and if they can read the int then they can copy it into a non-const int.

But from your comments it sounds like what you have in reality is not an `int` but a more complex user defined type, some sort of container perhaps. You can easily create an immutable container. This container could be a wrapper, or alternative implementation of your existing container. It then doesn't matter if the caller uses a const or non-const variable it is still immutable.

```
class MyClass {
  std::vector<int> data;
public:
  MyClass(size_t size) : data(size) {}
  int& operator[](size_t index) { return data[index]; }
  int operator[](size_t index) const { return data[index]; }
  size_t size() const { return data.size(); }
};

class MyClassImmutable {
  MyClass mc;
public:
  MyClassImmutable(MyClass&& mc) : mc(std::move(mc)){}
  int operator[](size_t index) const { return mc[index]; }
  size_t size() const { return mc.size(); }
  const MyClass& get() const { return mc; }
};

MyClassImmutable foo() {
  MyClass mc(100);
  mc[10] = 3;
  return mc;
}

void func(const MyClass& mc);

int main() {
    MyClassImmutable mci = foo();
    std::cout << mci[10] << "\n";  // Can read individual values
    //mci[10] = 4; // Error immutable
    func(mc.get());  // call function taking a const MyClass&
}
```

[Live demo.](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vLBUNnLiDmeWwn7d)

Of course there is nothing to stop the caller from copying each and every value from your immutable container and inserting them into a mutable container.

**Edit:** An alternative approach might be to return a smart pointer-to-const. The only downside is you have to pay for a dynamic memory allocation:

```
std::unique_ptr<const MyClass> foo() {
  auto mc = std::make_unique<MyClass>(100);
  (*mc)[10] = 3;
  return mc;
}

void func(const MyClass& mc);

int main() {
    auto mc = foo();
    std::cout << (*mc)[10] << "\n";  // Can read individual values
    //(*mc)[10] = 4; // Error const
    func(*mc);  // can pass to a function taking a const MyClass&
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is cool, but not quite what I needed. You are right that I don't really need it for `int`s but instead for a container type. The problem though is that later in the code I need to pass the container to various existing functions, which (in your example) would take a `const MyClass&` as an argument, not a `MyClassImmutable`. Perhaps, could we use inheritance rather than composition in `MyClassImmutable`?

Comment: @RafaelSpring It would be reasonable for `MyClassImmutable` to expose a `const MyClass&` (added). You could use inheritance, for example you could have a read-only interface `IMyClass` and return a smart-pointer to the read-only interface but then you couldn't pass that to a function taking a `const MyClass&` (you could update all those functions to use the interface). I've added an alternative that might work though.

Comment: Ah, yes great. Could have thought of this myself so thanks for pointing it out explicitly.

Comment: @RafaelSpring You could argue that exposing `const MyClass&` defeats the point a little because you can copy directly to a mutable copy: `MyClass m = foo().get()` which is precisely what you were trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes, but not what I was trying to avoid. Since you are returning `const MyClass&` the underlying buffer would still be immutable. You can always make a copy of the object, just as you can make a copy of a `const int`. You just can't change what's in it when it's `const`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. `foo()` has no way of knowing about the type of the left hand side of the assignment, because when the assignment itself happens, `foo()` is already evaluated. The best you could hope for is to change the return value, to try and cause a type-based error on the initialization:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct my_int {
  const int m;
  template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value, T>::type* = nullptr>
  constexpr operator T() const {return m;}
};

constexpr my_int foo() { return {5};}

int main() {
  const int a = foo();
  int b = foo();
}
```

[Live example](http://goo.gl/xLpwlN)

But this will also not work, because the typename in the template will never be substitued by a const-qualified type (in this specific case, it will be `int` for both lines in `main()`).

Answer (score 0):

As the following is possible

```
const int x = 4;
int y = x;
```

the C++ language will not provide such a mechanism.

Remains making a int const by a macro mechanism.

```
#define int_const_foo(var) const int var = ___foo()

int_const_foo(a);
```

Drawback: foo cannot be hidden, and the syntax is no longer C style.